# View not visible in device but visible in XML

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to build a layout with a right arrow and a vertical line with 2 textviews to right of it.

This layout will be used in a `RecyclerView`

This is the code that I am using,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"

    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"            
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/app_margin"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            >

            <View
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/lineView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lineView"


                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/type"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lineView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/name"

                />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/right_arrow"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"

                android:id="@+id/right_arrow"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the result of the above layout

[image]

The blue line is not visible when I run the output on my device but is visible in XML as shown

**My Questions**

1. How do I make it visible in my device ?
2. The blue line is very big I tried `wrap_content` but still did not work

Comment: I tried this code and the blue line is visible on both Editor and the actual device. Which device are you using?

Comment: @NovoLucas Device is Redmi Note 3

Comment: Strange, even I am using a Redmi and it's visible. Though its good that the problem is resolved.

Comment: @NovoLucas but no idea why it wasn't visible in mine

Comment: @NovoLucas I tried the below answers and the `lineView` is not visible

Comment: Have you tried on an Emulator?

Comment: @NovoLucas Sorry for the trouble issue resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply align your `lineView` upto the height of text views. otherwise it will grow upto the device height. Refer this sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:contentPadding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/view"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABCD"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/value"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="ABCD"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24px" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Screenshot of above example:
[image]

Comment: `lineView` is not visible

Comment: Device is redmi Note 3

Comment: I am soryy, my bad, just replace `android:layout_alignParentStart="true"` with `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` in lineview . I will update my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

To fit the line according to content use this

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

                   <View
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/lineView"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lineView"


                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/type"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lineView"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/name"

                    />
<LinearLayout />
```

Comment: Want it in a `RelativeLayout`